# todos method .sort() in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am interested in a question about todos sorting in typescript imagine that when choosing a sorting method, the sort function is called for tasks

there is an interface Todo

```
interface ITodo {
  title: string
  body: string
  id: number
  completed: boolean
}
```

the todos array itself

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState<ITodo[]>([])
```

Sorting is selected using the select tag if necessary, this is what the component looks like

```
<Select
    value={filter.sort}
    onChange={(selectedSort) => setFilter({ ...filter, sort: selectedSort })}
    options={[
       { value: 'title', name: 'By tilte' },
       { value: 'body', name: 'By body' }
    ]}
    defaultValue='Sorting'
/>
```

problematic function of sorting todos

```
const sortedTodos = useMemo(() => {
    if (sort)
        return [...todos].sort((a:ITodo, b:ITodo) => a[sort].localeCompare(b[sort]));            
    return todos;
}, [sort, todos]);
```

for example, if I pass the current string here for the selected sorting method, then everything works.Like this.

```
const sortedTodos = useMemo(() => {
    if (sort)
        return [...todos].sort((a:ITodo, b:ITodo) => a['title'].localeCompare(b['title']));            
    return todos;
}, [sort, todos]);
error:
```

The element is implicitly of type "any", since an expression of type "string" cannot be used for indexing of type "Todo". An index signature with a parameter of type "string" was not found in the "ITodo" type.

[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-frog-5fj6qt?file=/src/index.css)

Answer (score 0):

Try to define a type representing the keys of `ITodo`:

```
type TodoKey = keyof ITodo;
```

Then, declare the `sort` state as `TodoKey`:

```
const [sort, setSort] = useState<TodoKey>('title')
```

The type error should disappear.